Discontinuity across branch cuts in multivariate contour integration
I was wondering what the procedure is when you are crossing branch cuts (or, more precisely, branch surfaces) and picking up discontinuities along a multivariate complex contour.

For instance, if I had the function $F(x,y)=x^a\, y^b$, with $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$, then the branch curves (analog of branch points in 2d) would be at $x=0$ and $y=0$.
Let's say my initial contour is a square $r_-\leq x,y\leq r_+$ ($r_\pm>0$).
Then, to the edge $x=r_-$, I attach a tube that goes around $x=0$ in the complex plane while
maintaining each value of $y$ fixed (so $x=r_- e^{i\theta}, r_-\leq y\leq r_+$ with $0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$), and I do the same at the
$y=r_-$ edge with the $y$ coordinate. If I now integrate again over the square, what phases have I picked up, and when?

I cannot precisely visualize how this would be computed.

I advise you the book "Visual Complex Analysis" by T. Needham

@JeanMarie thanks! Is there any particular section that focuses on this topic?

I will have a look, but prior to that, see this old question here with an answer of mine about cases with exponents $1/2$.
